# Changing column from source to column with unique key constraint - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS and I am doing small data migration. I have column in my destination database `col1` which has Unique Key constraint and the data is in "xxxx01" -form.

What I need to do is to shorten the source data from `col2` to four first characters (xxxx) and add running number to the end if the first part is the same with other row. So for example destination data would look like `fest01, fest02, fest03, test01,kest01`.

In my source table there might be little under 80 rows that has the same value in `source.col2` so running number has to go at least high as that.

Answer (score 1):

Add into your package `OLEDB Source` with `SQL command` like this:

```
/* sample data */    
declare @t table (v varchar(50))
insert @t values('sadasvasv'),('sdfvadvssdv')
/* the SQL command */    
SELECT LEFT(v,4)+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(v,4) ORDER BY v) as varchar(50)) AS col1
FROM @t
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Tested it this way, but it doesn't work like planned. With this solution it uses the Rownumber as the running number. So source.col2 with values fest, fest, fest, test, kest will come out as 'fest1,fest2,fest3,test4,kest5' instead of running number only when the first part is the same (ex. fest1, fest2, fest3, test1,kest1)

Comment: @kepak221 Add `PARTITION BY LEFT(col2,4)` before `ORDER BY`.